# Multiline in CGridView column

Tags: yii, multiline, paragraph, cgridview

I have been searching through the internet for an answer to my question but I haven't found one. My problem is that I have column in my CGridView that contains a blob. My blob is a comment that is written by some users and can be edited. The comment can have a single sentence or can contain many paragraphs. In that case, I want to be sure that in my CGridView the separation between the paragraphs are visible.

For now, my CGridView is displaying the comment but doesn't respect the lineskips. How do I do that?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'grid-demande',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderDemande,
'emptyText'=>'No data',
'cssFile'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/css/my_gridview.css",
'columns'=>array
(
    array(            
        'name'=>'ch_comment',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'21%'),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following for your column definition in the gridview:

```
array(            
    'name'=>'ch_comment',
    'value'=>'nl2br($data->ch_comment)',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'21%'),
),
```

This will convert line breaks to `<br />` tags, which should solve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the formatter 'ntext': 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter#formatNtext-detail

In this case, in the 'columns' array just add:

```
'ch_comment:ntext',
//short forme
array(
  'name' => 'ch_comment',
  'type' => 'ntext'),
//long forme
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide some additional context to this answer for the benefit of the OP, such as an example using ntext?

Comment: This should really be marked as solution. The other "solutions" are just hacks, really.

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing `type=>'raw'` to `type=>'html'`